# Give value in header using variable in php

Tags: php, header

I am trying to pass a variable thorugh HTML anchor tag thorugh form. On form submit the value in anchor is passed to my .php file . Here in php file I have stored the passed value in a variable and now I want to use this value in header.

index.html 
 In below HTML I am passing variable "text1.pdf" to form.php

```
<a href="#" title="Download" target="_blank" onclick="document.myform.formVar.value='text1.pdf';document.myform.submit(); return false">Download</a>

<form method=post name="myform" action="form.php" style="display:none;">
<input type="hidden" name="formVar" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Send form!">
```

Form.php

```
$fileName = $_POST['formVar'];  
// Defining file URL
$fileURL="pdf/";
$fileURL .=$fileName;
header( "Location: ".$fileURL);
```

Here I am trying to form a URL using passed variable. And trying to put that variable in header. But I am not able to reach to that specific file. When I submit form on form.php it gets redirected to "pdf/" url instead of "pdf/text.pdf" .

Comment: This isn't very secure.  What's to stop somebody from modifying the POST data and downloading other files?

Answer (score 1):

In Form.php:

```
$fileURL .=$fileURL;
```

should be

```
$fileURL .=$fileName;
```